# Dependency errors. Sudo apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dependencies

Whenever I run `sudo apt update`
I get this result

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Problem parsing dependency 21 of libx32gcc-10-dev:i386=10-20200411-0ubuntu1
E: Error occurred while processing libx32gcc-10-dev (NewVersion2)
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: I am using UBUNTU 20.04 LTS

Comment: I can't install anything and can't open minecraft-launcher

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 20.04 LTS @David

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a backup of the old lists directory and update apt again:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /var/lib/apt/oldlists
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
```